# PhoneGap iOS Application needs to be opened twice to work

Tags: ios, phonegap

So i have this project developed on PhoneGap, the project works as expected on Android, my only problem in IOS is the project needs to be opened twice to work. To elaborate on that problem, at First attempt of opening/running the app on IOS, it only show background but does not execute functions and does not redirect, but if the user minimize the app and open it again. the APP will work as expected.

I'm so confused, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check if there is any error in the console on app open? Or any network request if you have, are those failing?

Comment: @sSD the console shows no error upon opening the App. It's just confusing that it only occurs in IOS. Maybe its a platform error or something.